# Why is _ special in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select 'ab' like 'a_%';
+-----------------+
| 'ab' like 'a_%' |
+-----------------+
|               1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'ab' like 'a\_%';
+------------------+
| 'ab' like 'a\_%' |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'a_b' like 'a\_%';
+-------------------+
| 'a_b' like 'a\_%' |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why do I need to escape `_`?

Comment: A Google search for "mysql like underscore" would have found you the information you desired. (Even just "mysql underscore".)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `_` and `%` are both special characters for `LIKE`.

`_` matches one character, `%` any number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
"_" means underscore. I think "_" used for hiding any character under it. It is special because we can place character for it.
```

You can get more from these links:

[link1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

[link2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

[link3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

[link4](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/refman/@Generic__BookTextView/26021;pt=26603)

[link5](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/6605;pt=7889)

[link6](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=meaning+of+wild+cards+for+like+query&oq=meaning+of+wild+cards+for+like+query&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=10713l14469l0l16111l10l9l0l0l0l2l2159l3539l7-1.0.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=fb23191ac5673b89&biw=1366&bih=608)